# How to have unnumbered chapters (included from other .tex files) in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters, include

I'm sorry, I'm new to latex and still have much to learn.

I'm using the `report` document class and also `openright`.
And this is what my "structure" looks like:

```
\tableofcontents


\setstretch{1.5}

\include{Introduction} 
\include{Chap1}
\include{Chap2}
\include{Chap3}
\include{Conclusions}
```

With *Introduction* and *Conclusions* starting with `chapter*{}` in order to have them as unnumbered chapters (and all of them being single .tex files, of course).

How do I have them unnumbered but also appearing in the TOC with the **correct page numbering**?
The only way I found was `\addcontentsline`, but the lines in the TOC reported wrong page numbers.

Thanks everybody in advance for the help!!

EDIT: forgot to say that I specified that I'm using `openright` since maybe that's the problem with wrong numbering.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example following the demands you find here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952, so that we can better understand the problem you are encountering.

Comment: Where are you putting the `\addcontentsline`? You should put it right after `\chapter*` in the intro/conclusion sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the `\addcontentsline` *after* the `\chapter*` command.

```
% tocincprob.tex  SE 590518
\documentclass[openright]{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\setstretch{1.5}  %%% where does this come from?
\chapter*{Intooduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter{Chap1}
\chapter{Chap2}
\chapter*{Conclusions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I tried everything but this, I didn't know it had to go in the other .tex file.. as I said, I still have much to learn! Thanks again.

I don't know if it was a question for me, anyway I forgot to delete `\setstretch` as I copied that code part.